# Problems setting up custom FB Signup with Meteor and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

So I have been trying to create a custom FB login with Meteor and React but I am stuck.

I got so far that I am able to signup with FB, create the user in my database but now my current user displays as undefined undefined instead of the first and last name.

I understand that I need to set the values somewhere but I am kinda lost on where or how I should do this.

If anyone has experience setting this up, please give me a push in the right direction.

This is my current code for the signup form:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { Row, Col, FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { handleSignup } from '../../modules/signup';

export class Signup extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    handleSignup({ component: this });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

    socialLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const service = event.target.getAttribute( 'data-social-login' ),
          options = {
            requestPermissions: [ 'email' ]
          };

    if ( service === 'loginWithTwitter' ) {
      delete options.requestPermissions;
    }

    Meteor[ service ]( options, ( error ) => {
      if ( error ) {
        Bert.alert( error.message, 'danger' );
      }
    });
  }



  render() {
    return (
    <div className="login-form">
      <Col xs={12} md={4} sm={4} />
        <Col xs={ 12 } md={ 4 } sm={ 4 } >
          <h4 className="page-header">Sign Up</h4>
          <form ref="signup" className="signup" onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={ 6 } sm={ 6 }>
                <FormGroup>
                  <ControlLabel>First Name</ControlLabel>
                  <FormControl
                    type="text"
                    ref="firstName"
                    name="firstName"
                    placeholder="First Name"
                  />
                </FormGroup>
              </Col>
              <Col xs={ 6 } sm={ 6 }>
                <FormGroup>
                  <ControlLabel>Last Name</ControlLabel>
                  <FormControl
                    type="text"
                    ref="lastName"
                    name="lastName"
                    placeholder="Last Name"
                  />
                </FormGroup>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <FormGroup>
              <ControlLabel>Email Address</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                type="text"
                ref="emailAddress"
                name="emailAddress"
                placeholder="Email Address"
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                type="password"
                ref="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <Button type="submit" bsStyle="success">Sign Up</Button>
          </form>
          <hr/>
          <Button className= "fb-button" data-social-login="loginWithFacebook" type="button" onClick={ this.socialLogin }>
            <i className="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in with Facebook
          </Button>

          <p>Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Log In</Link>.</p>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} md={4} sm={4} />
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And this is my handleSignup file:

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-validation';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import { Bert } from 'meteor/themeteorchef:bert';
import { getInputValue } from './get-input-value';

let component;

const getUserData = () => ({
  email: getInputValue(component.refs.emailAddress),
  password: getInputValue(component.refs.password),
  profile: {
    name: {
      first: getInputValue(component.refs.firstName),
      last: getInputValue(component.refs.lastName),
    },
  },
});

const signUp = () => {
  const user = getUserData();

  Accounts.createUser(user, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      Bert.alert(error.reason, 'danger');
    } else {
      browserHistory.push('/');
      Bert.alert('Welcome!', 'success');
    }
  });
};

const validate = () => {
  $(component.refs.signup).validate({
    rules: {
      firstName: {
        required: true,
      },
      lastName: {
        required: true,
      },
      emailAddress: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6,
      },
    },
    messages: {
      firstName: {
        required: 'First name?',
      },
      lastName: {
        required: 'Last name?',
      },
      emailAddress: {
        required: 'Need an email address here.',
        email: 'Is this email address legit?',
      },
      password: {
        required: 'Need a password here.',
        minlength: 'Use at least six characters, please.',
      },
    },
    submitHandler() { signUp(); },
  });
};

export const handleSignup = (options) => {
  component = options.component;
  validate();
};
```

When I run console.log(Accounts) in the console of Chrome I get this returned, is that correct? :

```js
ccountsClient
LOGIN_TOKEN_EXPIRES_KEY
:
"Meteor.loginTokenExpires"
LOGIN_TOKEN_KEY
:
"Meteor.loginToken"
USER_ID_KEY
:
"Meteor.userId"
_accountsCallbacks
:
Object
_autoLoginEnabled
:
true
_hashPassword
:
(password)
_lastLoginTokenWhenPolled
:
null
_loggingIn
:
false
_loggingInDeps
:
Tracker.Dependency
_loginServicesHandle
:
Object
_onLoginFailureHook
:
Hook
_onLoginHook
:
Hook
_onLogoutHook
:
Hook
_options
:
Object
_pageLoadLoginAttemptInfo
:
null
_pageLoadLoginCallbacks
:
Array[0]
_pollIntervalTimer
:
3
changePassword
:
(oldPassword, newPassword, callback)
connection
:
Connection
createUser
:
(options, callback)
forgotPassword
:
(options, callback)
oauth
:
Object
resetPassword
:
(token, newPassword, callback)
users
:
Mongo.Collection
verifyEmail
:
(token, callback)
__proto__
:
AccountsCommon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you already managed to to create an user account for FB login. What you need to do now is to set up this hook on server [Meteor.onCreateUser](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-onCreateUser), inside this hook you could set `profile` object of the newly created user:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {

  user.profile = {};

  if (user.services.facebook) {
    const faceProfile = user.services.facebook;

    // merge default profile with facebook profile
    options.profile = {
      ...options.profile,
      firstName: faceProfile.first_name,
      lastName: faceProfile.last_name,
      avatar: `//graph.facebook.com/${faceProfile.id}/picture/?type=large`,
    };

    // if you want to set emails too
    options.emails = [
      {
        address: faceProfile.email,
      }
    ];
  }

  if (options.profile) {
    user.profile = options.profile;
  }

  if (options.emails) {
    user.emails = options.emails;
  }

  return user;
});
```

Comment: Ah of course...! Thanks so much for taking the time to write this reply. I do get an error though, when I try to add this to my application on the server side, I get this error: 
TypeError: Accounts.onCreateUser is not a function(…)

I haven't slept tonight, maybe that is why I can't figure it out myself :p

Comment: Do you have `accounts-base` package in `.meteor/packages` file?

Comment: Yes I do: accounts-base without a version constraint has already been added.

Comment: hmm I have no idea, maybe you should try `console.log(Accounts)` prior to call `Accounts.onCreateUser` to see what it is really

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the push in the right direction! :-D

Comment: Pretty weird, I am able to call console.log(Accounts) in the console of Chrome and it does return a lot. 

Is this what it is supposed to return? I added it to the code.

Comment: yes it is. Try it in server side, or if you know `meteor shell` you could try `console.log(Accounts.onCreateUser)` in the shell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129801/discussion-between-deelux-and-khang).

Comment: Whoop Whoop! It is working! Just had to change some variables in the document your suplied and now it's working like a charm! Thank you soooo much!

Comment: I am interested in knowing the getInputValue method definition